# Laravel relationship returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch database data through a model relationship in Laravel.
I've set up one model, like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Userskeywords extends Eloquent {

    public function relatedKeywords()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Keywords', 'id', 'keywordId');
    }

}
?>
```

And the other model is just a normal model. In the database they look like this:

**Keywords**

[image]

**UsersKeywords**

[image]

However, when I run `UsersKeywords::with('relatedKeywords')->get()` it returns `NULL`for `related_keywords`. This happens when the following code is executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
$keywords = Userskeywords::where('user', '=', $id)->get();
$keywords->load('relatedKeywords');
return Response::json($keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is called **relatedKeywords** so you need to access related object with

```
$object->relatedKeywords
```

instead of

```
$object->related_keywords
```

Comment: This throws an sql error. I don't think this is right.

Comment: That column `keywordId` can't be found on the table. It's looking in the wrong table, so the original is okay.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's 2:30 over here :) I think I know the reason, updating the answer.

Comment: I updated my question as well. I'm not accessing it straight from the object. I'm returning the complete object as JSON.

Comment: I understand that the JSON that you return has a key "relatedKeywords:null", correct?

Comment: It's a key called `related_keywords:null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87066/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-user4992124).